# Missing/white text in both both visual and html text editors, Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ftp, web-config

I make frequent updates to the website for a small, regional food and wine festival (duxburyfoodandwinefestival.com, built using Wordpress). When I recently went to edit/update the site on Wordpress with information on this year's events, I was (and still am) unable to view existing content in the text editor fields (both visual and text). The text is there when I highlight, but it's all white.

So far, I have tired updating my theme, clearing my browser cache, trying a different browser (two, actually), adding a Google Libraries plugin that online research suggested could help-- nothing has worked. I suspect that there must be something I need to do to the config file via ftp, but I have no experience with this and am feeling pretty stymied. Any ideas from those more knowledgeable than I?

Thanks in advance; I didn't encounter this issue last year, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

[One page of content as it appears online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj4SQ.jpg)
[The same page of content in text editor view, content invisible/white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOpxm.png)
[Highlighting show that the text is present, but white on white field-- not useful for editing/composing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrb8F.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue. My particular problem had to do with the most recent update to WordPress and a conflict with an existing plugin on our site ("WP Memory Load and db size Usage"). I opened a second browser window and systematically tried deactivating one plugin at a time until I reached the problem child (it was last, of course). By refreshing my content editor view in a separate window after each plugin deactivation, I was able to isolate the problem plugin. When I deactivated the plugin in question and refreshed my content editor view, the text returned to black/visible in both visual and html text views. I am now operating as-normal with that single plugin deactivated.